# Рекомендації щодо теґів? / Tag recomendations?

Tags: discussion, tags

На сайті багато теґів, весь час пропонують зміни теґів питань. Але я не бачу опису цим теґам. Де можна знайти такий опис?

Наприклад, є теґ pronounciation і phonetics. Коли який використовувати? Чи дуже дивний для мене теґ "soft-sign". Скільки питань можна поставити про мʼякий знак? :)
Бачу пропозицію змінити теґ names на proper-names...

There are many tags on site. Tag changes are proposed all the time. I can't find description of tags. Where can I find such description?

For example, there is "pronounciation" and "phonetics" tag. When should I use wich? There is also very strange (in my opinion) tag "soft-sign. How many questions can be asked about soft sign? :) Also there is suggestion to change tag "names" to "proper-names"...

Comment: Дивись тут: Private Beta пункти 2. та 3. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/196120

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це дуже гарня ідея.

Я давно вже думав створити питання з wiki-відповіддю, де б описувалася основна структура теґів (найголовніші теґи). Спочатку туди можна написати *запропоновану* структуру. Після синхронізації з реальністю туди вже вноситимуться зміни лише *по факту* реального створення теґів (можливо, в випадку складних рішень навіть так: обговорити неоднозначну ситуацію в окремому питанні => створити теґи за результатами обговорення => внести в загальну wiki-інфу, якщо вони значні).

<sub>Там же внизу можна писати прохання щодо якихось змін, які очевидно потрібні, але людина через занизький рейтинг поки що зробити не може.</sub>

P. S.: Насправді кожен теґ може мати [usage guidance (короткий і докладний)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3). І добре, якби всі вони його мали. Але, по-моєму, це не замінює ідею про створення wiki-відповіді з основною структурою теґів, тому що:

- в usage guidance можна почитати про теґ, що ти *вже* (випадково чи після довгого пошуку) знайшов, але воно не дозволяє оцінити загальну структуру чи ходити по ній;
- як бачимо більшість (100%?) теґів по факту usage guidance'а не мають: частково тому що людям ліньки, частково бо це вимагає репутації (чи модерації).

> <sub>Наприклад, я пропоную певинну структуру теґів зробити за класичними розділами мовознавства.</sub>
>   <sub>Правда, виникає питання: українського чи англійського (бо класифікація трішки різниться). Я пропоную — українського.</sub>
>
> - лексика ← lexicon
> - фонетика ← phonetics, вимова, pronunciation
> - орфографія ← spelling
>
>   - небуквенні-орфограмми ← inword-punctuation
> - пунктуація ← text-punctuation
> - етимологія ← etymology
> - синтаксис ← syntax
> - морфологія ← morphology
> - тощо
>
> <sub>Увага: зараз обговорюється не конкретно ця структура, а сама ідея створення wiki-відповіді зі структурою і необхідність обговорення первинної структури в ме́ті. Якщо сама ідея отримає підтримку, то *ця*, чи *інша пропонована*, чи *де-факто наявна* структура буде винесена в окреме повідомлення і вже там буде обговорюбватися.</sub>

Comment: Слушні поради щодо тегів тут: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/196120 Private Beta пункти 2. та 3.

Comment: Прийняв цю відповідь, бо вважаю таку вікі-відповідь вкрай потрібною. @Sasha, створиш?
"usage guidence" зовсім не замінює, бо там купа теґів, купа з яких синоніми, і нереально продивитися їх усі. А так можна буде доволі швидко вибрати теґ. Ті описи, гадаю, дуже корисні, коли під час редагування вирішуєш, чи варто змінювати теґ. А коли створюєш питання, то така вікі-відповідь була б значно зручнішою.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, [ось](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/51/4). Хоча вийшло все якось набагато гірше, ніж я думав.

Comment: @KyryloYatsenko, я подумав і вирішив, що то повна фігня. (Ну, ідея про те, що слід створити 10 широких тегів і намагатися, щоб кожне питання містило хоча б 1 з них — типу як тут discussion/bug/support/feature-request.) Ось [нова відповідь, де я намагаюся лише класифікувати наявні теги](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/86/4).